# How to embed RTMP video stream player on webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, embed, jwplayer, rtmp

Is there any free/open/customizable solution?

I heard about `jwplayer` but i cound't get it to work using their page structions, like the following:

```
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/XXzG4ndHEeS3EA6sC0aurw.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    jwplayer("cover").setup({
        file: "rtmp://199.59.88.39/cam4-cr107/130.flv",
        image: "start.png",
        height: 360,
        width: 640
    }); 
});
</script>
```

What I'm I doing wrong? Any other better player suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in this line `jwplayer("#cover").setup({`

Also you forget to add  `<div id=cover></div>`
Try this code:

```
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/XXzG4ndHEeS3EA6sC0aurw.js"></script>
<div id=cover></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    jwplayer("cover").setup({
        file: "rtmp://199.59.88.39/cam4-cr107/130.flv",
        image: "start.png",
        height: 360,
        width: 640
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: I had already noticed this "#" problem right after posting here. Thank you anywhay but this do not solve my problem. Any other clues?

Comment: so give a link where you run this